# Draw vertical lines in chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization, angular-nvd3

Is there any way to draw vertical lines in chart. (i.e.)
[image]

Under each dot  there is a vertical line which is projected to x axis.

Could you advise how to customize it with Google Chart , of course if it is possible?

Are there any other libraries with such kind of line chart ?

p.s. In project I use Angular 1.5.  Also I  took a look on nvd3 but didn't find what I want

Comment: Does this help https://medium.com/fattura-con-billy/animated-stacked-bar-charts-with-d3-js-2ef928163e59#.rmg7bjofk

Comment: @Adapter Thank you for your attention, but first of all I'd like to customize existing implementation, if it is possible, if not -  I will  consider other ways.

Answer (score 0):

see [config options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options)...

use option for `vAxis.gridlines` to customize *vertical lines*...

Comment: Thanks, I checked it, but there are no options for what I want

Comment: gridlines can be added manually, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42369874/5090771)...